# PHP login script

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I have the following PHP script for login. When I type valid credentials then it does not redirects to `index.php`. It simply reloads the page But when I type wrong credentials it gives me message which is OK.

My PHP code is as follows:

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);
    $sel_user = "SELECT * FROM `we_admins` WHERE admin_username = '$username' AND admin_password = '$password'";
    $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sel_user);
    $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
   while($row = $run_user->fetch_assoc()) {
      $_SESSION['admin_id'] = $row['admin_id'];
      $_SESSION['admin_id'];
   }
   if($check_user>0){
     $_SESSION["admin_username"]=$username;
     header('location: index.php');
   }
   else {
     echo "<script>alert('Username or password is not correct, try again!')</script>";
   }
  }
```

I have a function for those users which are not logged in and it is seems to be fine also(I think), which I have called on every page of the project.

PHP code to check logged in as follows:

```
function is_logged_in() {
global $con;
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin_username'])){
    header('Location: login.php');
}
}
```

Comment: Then, just replace the condition !

Comment: please look at this `header('location: dashboard/index.php');` maybe 'Location' is case sensitive

Comment: @Shafee Please see my answer below

Comment: You might want to die() or close the connection after that header..

Comment: Remember: after each `header();` you have to `exit;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, luthando-loot is right. The *Location* is case-sensitive.

Try to replace: `header('location: dashboard/index.php');`
with: `header('Location: dashboard/index.php');`

And, for better comprehension, use absolute path, like explained [in this document](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/9296-php-redirect-to-another-page-redirect-header).

---

Else, it could be that something is already sent to the user, so you cannot modify the header anymore.

> Remember that header() must be called **before any actual output is sent**, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

(from the [PHP header function page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php))

---

And after a `header('Location: ...');`, you have to use the `exit;` function.

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition for the redirect is looking for a different `$_SESSION` variable (admin_username not client_username) - so the conditional redirect is triggering when you try to redirect on successful login.

Change the if statement in your redirect to
`if(!isset($_SESSION['client_username'])){`

Answer (score 0):

In function is_logged_in , you are checking

> $_SESSION['admin_username'],

but in login page you have

> $_SESSION["client_username"]=$username

maybe problem is there

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put `session_start();` at top of each script

and in the login script put:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['admin_username'])){ 
     header("location: index.php");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There was some extra sessions assignments. And the while loop was useless.
Reshaped the code.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);
        $sel_user = "SELECT * FROM `we_admins` WHERE admin_username = '$username' AND admin_password = '$password'";
        $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sel_user);
        $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
      if($check_user<0){
        echo "<script>alert('Username or password is not correct, try again!')</script>";
        exit;
      }else{
        $row = $run_user->fetch_assoc();
        $_SESSION["admin_id"] = $row['admin_id'];
        $_SESSION["admin_username"] = $row['admin_username'];
        header('location: ./index.php');
        exit;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
I check this code it works fine. 
session_start();
include('conn.php');

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 $email = $_POST["email"];
 $password=$_POST["password"];
  if (empty($password)) {
     $error['password'] = "Password number is required";
   } 
  if (empty($email)) {
      $error['email'] = "Email is required";
   } else {

     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $error['email'] = "Invalid email format";
     }
 } 
if(!$error)
{
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'";
//echo $sql;
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);    
if($count==1)
{
$_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id'];
$_SESSION['login_user']=$email;
$_SESSION['img']=$row['pro_img'];
$_SESSION['name']=$row['name'];
header("location: view_topic.php");
}
else
{
$error['page']="Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
}
```

}  }

```
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.tablescroll.css"/>
<body style="background-color:#E0FFFF">
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Login</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr><span class="error"> <?php echo $error['page'];?></span></tr>
<tr>
<td width="14%"><strong>Username:</strong></td>
<td width="2%">:</td>
<td width="84%"><input type="text" name="email" /> <span class="error">* <?php echo $error['email'];?></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top"><strong>password</strong></td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td width="84%"><input type="password" name="password" /> <span class="error">* <?php echo $error['password'];?></span></td>
</tr>

<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" />   </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: realize that code has SQL injection vunrabilities in $_POST["email"] and $_POST["password"]; ? :p